# How to best access elements of std::pair?

Tags: c++, std-pair

While using std::pair I came across two different approaches to access its elements. As they both seem to be valid and working I was wondering what is the difference between them and which approach is the preferred one?

```
std::pair<int, int> p(1,1); // can be of any type.
int i1 = p.first;        // first approach
int i2 = std::get<0>(p); // second approach
```

Comment: Both are equivalent and okay. Which one to "prefer" is a matter of style and personal preference.

Comment: `std::get` works for some other types, like `tuple`, so is useful in templated code. No other specific advantage.

Comment: If I would need to use `std::tuple` and `std::pair` in one project, I would get rid of `std::pair` from a project.

Comment: @S.M. good luck changing `std::map<...>::value_type` etc.

Comment: @Caleth `std` is not my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in a given application, either of `pair` or `0` is not a literal but a parameter, use `get`:

```
template<class... T> auto sum0(const T&... t) {
  return (std::get<0>(t)+...);
}

template<int i> auto sqrAt(const std::pair<int,double> &p) {
  const auto v=std::get<i>(p);
  return v*v;
}
```

If both `pair` and `0` are present literally, using `.first` is plainly preferable for readability reasons (including that it indicates the conscious use of `std::pair`):

```
template<class M>
void addKeys(M &m) {
  for(auto &kv : m) kv.second+=kv.first;
}
```

Everything about this function indicates intended use with `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, making it very readable despite the only type named being `void`.